# Accessing Python 3x dictionary values for a variable dictionary name

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary, python-module

I have a Python 3.7.3 file, `specs.py`, containing multiple dictionaries with the same keys.

```
f150 = {
    'towing-capacity' : '3,402 to 5,897 kg',
    'horsepower' : '385 to 475 hp',
    'engine' : ' 2.7 L V6, 3.3 L V6, 3.5 L V6, 5.0 L V8'
}

f250 = {
    'towing-capacity' : '5,670 to 5,897 kg',
    'horsepower' : '290 to 450 hp',
    'engine' : '6.2 L V8, 6.7 L V8 diesel, 7.3 L V8'
}
```

In another file, I am importing `specs.py` and would like to be able to find the value associated with a given key for the variable `carmodel`.

```
hp = specs.{what should I put here so it equals cardmodel}.['horsepower']
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use

```
getattr(specs, carmodel)['horsepower']
```

Because global variables will be attributes on a module object.

But it would make more sense maybe to nest your dict further:

```
cars = {
'f150': {
    'towing-capacity' : '3,402 to 5,897 kg',
    'horsepower' : '385 to 475 hp',
    'engine' : ' 2.7 L V6, 3.3 L V6, 3.5 L V6, 5.0 L V8'
},

'f250' : {
    'towing-capacity' : '5,670 to 5,897 kg',
    'horsepower' : '290 to 450 hp',
    'engine' : '6.2 L V8, 6.7 L V8 diesel, 7.3 L V8'
}}}
```

Then you can use like:

```
specs.cars[carmodel]['horsepower']
```

Answer (score 1):

You can reference any attribute of any object (modules are objects too) by string in python using `getattr`

```
import specs
getattr(specs, 'f150')
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this like this:

```
import specs
specs.f150                                                                                                                                                                          

#{'towing-capacity': '3,402 to 5,897 kg',
# 'horsepower': '385 to 475 hp',
# 'engine': ' 2.7 L V6, 3.3 L V6, 3.5 L V6, 5.0 L V8'}

specs.f150['horsepower']                                                                                                                                                            
# '385 to 475 hp'
```